# Value doesn't get saved in database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there so i have my code running and actually works pretty ok, i don't have any error, but what makes me come here it's that one of the parts to fill up in my formulary "nombre" doesn't appear in the database row but my other info "edad" it does, what i'm doing bad? here is my code

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])){
$n= $_REQUEST['nombre'];

}
if(isset($_REQUEST['edad'])){
$e= $_REQUEST['edad'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO team VALUES (NULL,'$n','$e')");
echo "<script> alert('Se inserto registro');</script>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Base de datos</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Gestion de Base de Datos</h1><hr>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce nombre" required><br>
</form>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="edad" placeholder="Introduce edad" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="insertar">
</form>
```

here is a photo of what  happens when i insert this 2 required texts
http://postimg.org/image/9etdzqloz/

Comment: Karen, Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why form tag is two times. try putting on same tag

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce nombre" required><br>
<input type="text" name="edad" placeholder="Introduce edad" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="insertar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `}` after `$e=...` . So `$n` was unknown. 
The working code:

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])){
   $n= $_REQUEST['nombre'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['edad'])){
  $e= $_REQUEST['edad'];
} /* <== here */

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO team VALUES (NULL,'$n','$e')");
echo "<script> alert('Se inserto registro');</script>";
//} not here ;)
?>
```

---

**EDIT**

The `form`is wrong too :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce nombre" required><br>
<!-- DELETE THIS :
</form>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 -->
    <input type="text" name="edad" placeholder="Introduce edad" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="insertar">
</form>
```

Comment: still the same with nombre

Comment: Olé... aaah the issue is **also** the FORM. You got your answer.